# How to call variables generated in loop

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I need to generate a number of variables in a loop. I achieved this by using this code:

```
nBottom=list of initially unknown size
loc=locals()
for k,val in enumerate(nBottom) : loc["imp_local"+str(k)]=700
for k,val in enumerate(nBottom) : loc["imp_global"+str(k)]=600
```

Now I need to work with them, by creating a dictionary like:

```
dic1={'imp_local0': 700, ..., 'imp_localn': 700}
dic2={'imp_global0': 700, ..., 'imp_globaln': 700}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Change `loc=locals()` to `loc=dict()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't generate local variables. Just generate the dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'imp_local'+str(k):700 for k,val in enumerate(nBottom)}
dict2 = {'imp_global'+str(k):600 for k,val in enumerate(nBottom)}
```

Refer to [dict comprehensions (PEP 274)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for details

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever add variables by using locals. Especially since you actually want that data to be in a dictionary in the end. Just add it to the dictionary from the start:

```
nBottom=list of initially unknown size
dic1 = {}
dic2 = {}
for k,val in enumerate(nBottom) : dic1["imp_local"+str(k)]=700
for k,val in enumerate(nBottom) : dic2["imp_global"+str(k)]=600
```

Done!